# ajax response byte size

Tags: javascript, jquery, size, response, jsonp

I'm using jQuery's getJSONP and I want to log the duration of the call and the size of the response to be able to have some statistics about the usage of my application. 
This is a cross domain ajax call, so I need to use JSONP, but as the JSONP call is not done with an XMLHttpRequest object, the complete callback from jquery's ajax doesn`t pass the response content.

So my question is how to get the response size (content lenght) from a JSONP call.

```
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    complete:function(x,e)
    {
         log(x.responseText.length, x.responseText);
    }
}
```

here x is a XMLHttpRequest object for a JSON call , but for JSONP call is undefined.

Comment: For security reasons, this is not possible.

Comment: Being pedantic, `x.responseText.length` gives you the *character* count, not the byte count.

Comment: hi SLaks, thanks for the quick answer, but then the question arises: 
is there a best practice for achieving this? for example I can have the response length as a direct property in the json response. but that means that if I have no control over the server side I cannot do that.

Comment: You could use your own server as a proxy and use ordinary AJAX.

Comment: @Alex: I think SLaks is (as usual) correct that you can't (although I quibble with his definition of *why*), there just isn't any way to do this. Basically what you're asking is for a way to get the length of an external script that is included in your page via a `script` tag (because that's how JSONP works, by temporarily inserting a `script` tag in your document). If you had control of the server side of things, then of course there are several ways you could do this, but if you don't...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get the "Content-Length" of the response header:

```
var contentsize;
$.ajax('url', function(data, textstatus, request) {
    contentsize = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") / 1024;
    //do stuff with your data
});
```

Comment: I tried this way, but for me content-length header is always returning 0 :(

Comment: This will not always work. It only works if the server includes the content-length header. Here's an image that you can retrieve that does not include the header: http://diarioveaonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/unique-beautiful-nature-wallpaper-for-desktop-free-download-16-5b2ff2c66582c.jpg

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax('url',function(data,textstatus,request)
{
     var totalBytes  = request.getResponseHeader('Content-length');

     //if u are looking for downloaded bytes
     var dlBytes =request.responseText.length; 
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: This answer is correct for each case.
Case 1: Response is Gzip
Case 2: Response is Plain