# Get the number of network bytes sent and received for an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, networking, packet

How can I get the number of bytes/packets sent and received for an AJAX call made using JavaScript.
I am able to see this data on the Firebug/Console, but is there a way to retrieve this information using JavaScript? I need to show this information for every AJAX call that I perform on my application to the end user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791860/jquery-how-to-check-the-size-of-the-response-object-in-an-ajax-call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645504/ajax-response-byte-size

Comment: Thanks guys, searched quite a while, couldn't find the relevant one. @FabrizioCalderan link helped. I have voted to close this question for duplication.