# How to know size of response in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have `ajax` request with `get` method which is return the some dynamic data. I want to check size of response and how much it loaded.

Basically I want to make a progress bar with javascript. There is plenty of plugins available on internet but I want to make my own with help.

So I just need reference how to get these thing done. there is two thing which I need is total data size (kb) and how much it loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645504/ajax-response-byte-size or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358138/get-the-length-of-jqquery-ajax-response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me

```
 var xhr = $.ajax({
      type: "HEAD",
      url: "path/to/file.ext",
      success: function(msg){
        alert(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length') + ' bytes');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
  type: "HEAD",
  url: "path/to/file.ext",
  success: function(msg){
    alert(msg.tostring().length);
  }
});
```

Comment: length property shows number of chars but not number of bytes. It matters for unicode strings